# How to run existing tests on a python lib cloned form github?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I downloaded a python lib from github.
I made a few changes to the source code.
I wanted to run the tests that it contained to see if I didn't break anything.

There is a tests directory at the top level along with a directory - xyz

Now this xyz package is being imported in a file inside the tests directory.

On running the test, I get an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'xyz'
```

What should I do to run the tests ?

Here is the lib: https://github.com/openx/OX3-Python-API-Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the test module doesn't have a main execution, you need a collector to run the tests. You also have to run the collector at the root of your repository so that python can find the module you're testing.

For instance, you could run:

```
~/OX3-Python-API-Client$ python -m unittest tests
```

Or install a test collector such as [nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/) and run:

```
~/OX3-Python-API-Client$ nosetests tests
```

Comment: even after using nose, the issue is that it still doesn't recognize modules from the project as they are not on pythonpath. Is there a way to specify which directories to add to pythonpath before running the tests ?

Comment: Messing with the python path is usually a bad idea. If you need a python package to be available, you should install it. In my case I had to install `oauth2` before I could run the tests. What is the package that you're missing?

Answer (score -2):

You need to make sure your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable contains `xyz` so the `python` interpreter is able to find and load it (it can also find it if `xyz` exists relative to your current directory). If `xyz` is a third-party library then you need to install it.